# Computing Var of mean of a sample from a normal distribution

Tags: variance

I need to calculate $\text{VAR}[\bar X]$ where $X_i$ are random sample of size $n$ from a normal distribution with mean $\theta$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

So I do $\text{VAR}[\bar X] = E[\bar X^2] -(E[\bar X])^2  $

$E[\bar X] = \theta$

How do I find $E[\bar X^2] $?

Comment: $\bar X$ has a known distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given,
$$\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$$
If $X_i$'s are independent then ([Wikipedia:Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance%20%22[1])),
$$\textrm{Var}[\bar{X}] = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n \textrm{Var}[X_i]$$
else
$$\textrm{Var}[\bar{X}] = \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \textrm{Var}[X_i] + 2\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}\textrm{Cov}[X_i, X_j]\right)$$

Now, based on what information is given to you, you can attempt to proceed ahead.